# C programing: Segmentation fault when reading numbers into a array

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I am baffled and looking for some help on what seems so simple. I am trying to set the size of an array in my main then call my function to have a user input the numbers into a array of that size. After running the program I get the output:

```
Enter how many: (users length of array)
Enter data: (users first number)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am wondering what I did wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int length, arr, size;

    printf("enter how many: ");
    scanf("%i", &length);

    readArray(arr, length);

    return 0;
}

int readArray(int arr[50], int length)
{
    int i, data;

    for (i =0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        printf("enter data %i: ", i);
        scanf("%i", data);
        arr[i] = data;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Looks like you're short one ampersand: `scanf("%i", &data);`

Comment: Why are you calling `readArray` with the first parameter as an `int`, when the first parameter should be an `int *`?

Comment: added it in and still coming up with that same error.

Comment: a question you should ask yourself - where is the memory for the array you intend to fill being allocated? right now you're not allocating anything, even on the stack.

Comment: eventually the program will have two functions to find the maximum and mode of the the array. So i will need the array to be used in other functions. with that said should i keep the memory of the array in my main?

Comment: You can't pass an array to `readArray()` unless you have an array to pass in the first place. So yes, you'll need to create it in `main()`. Right now you're passing a single `int`. The only reason your compiler isn't screaming at you is because you didn't provide a prototype for `readArray()` prior to calling it.

Comment: @PeterDowling - I think you need to know that `int readArray(int arr[50], int length)` does not declare an array as the first parameter.  It is no different than this: `int readArray(int* arr, int length)`.  That's why I asked why are you passing an `int` when the parameter type is an `int *`

Comment: The arr[50] in the function readArray the array im trying to put my users inputs into. Or should I declare the array by itself?

Comment: @PeterDowling - Did you read my comment?  The `arr[50]` you used in the function declaration is *not* an array, regardless of how "array-like" it looks.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did read it so i have to declare the array by itself before hand? perhaps in my main?

Comment: @PeterDowling - Yes, you must declare the array.  You didn't do that at all in your `main()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

void readArray( int arr[], int length );

int main(void)
{
    int length;

    printf( "enter how many: " );
    scanf( "%i", &length );

    int arr[length];

    readArray( arr, length );

    return 0;
}

void readArray( int arr[], int length )
{
    int i, data;

    for ( i = 0; i < length; ++i )
    {
        printf( "enter data %i: ", i );
        scanf( "%i", &data );
        arr[i] = data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `readArray` function declaration looks like this:

```
int readArray(int arr[50], int length)
```

That is, it takes and array of integers (`arr`) and an integer (`length`)

Your code in main however:

```
int length, arr, size;
//...
readArray(arr, length);
```

declares `arr` as an int.

To fix this, you need to declare arr as an array of size `length`:

```
printf( "enter how many: " );
scanf( "%i", &length );

int arr[length];  //declares an array 'arr' of size 'length'
```

Note that you also don't need to declare the size of the array in the `readArray` declaration.
Arrays in **C** are passed as pointers to the first element.  Therefore, the declaration should be:

```
int readArray(int arr[], int length)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
int readArray(int *arr, int length)
```

Finally, you did it correctly in `main` but in your `readArray` function, remember the `&` in the scanf function call:

```
scanf( "%i", &data );
```